# Hide output when an exception is thrown

Tags: php, exception

I just wanted to ask if there is any way to hide any output I already sent whenever my script encounters an exception. For example: I print an array and encounter an exception. At this point I only want to print the exception message, not the array output (because it may not be complete, due to the error).

Comment: register an exception handler that takes care of all uncaught exceptions. Have it clear the output buffer, and write the exception message to it instead, then exit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern may be what you want:

```
// Start output buffering
ob_start();

try {
    // Your code that might throw an error
    // ...

    // No errors: Send output to client
    flush();
    ob_end_flush();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Error occured. Throw away output and stop buffering
    ob_end_clean();

    // Handle your error
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is buffer (save to variable, for example) your output and check errors before echo it.